# Process Builder - missing "=" operator

Tags: process-builder

My first question post here. I have a Process Builder where I need to check that a priorvalue is not one of two picklist values on Work Order object. This fórmula is already in use with a similar custom object.

Error: The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

```
OR
(
(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE ([[WorkOrder].Status),"Fechado"))),
(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE ([[WorkOrder].Status),"Não é possível concluir")))
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!. Could you please add the full `formula` expression or provide the snapshot?. As per given details, I don't see any error. This given formula return `True` or `False` only, So can you please provide the details like which field your assign this formula?

Comment: Hi MohanRaj, thank you!! The full fórmula is only this one. Is a condition in PB. The field tested is "Status", a picklist field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have unbalanced square brackets `[[`. Change to:

```
OR
(
(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE ([WorkOrder].Status),"Fechado"))),
(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE ([WorkOrder].Status),"Não é possível concluir")))
)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help!